# How to show a QMessageBox completely before the next function call

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use a QMessageBox to announce a short waiting interval to the user.

```
QMessageBox* box(new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Information,"Parser","Processing " + mFileName));
box->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::NoButton);
box->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
box->show();
QApplication::processEvents();

parser.analyseFile(mFileName);

box->hide();
box->deleteLater();
QApplication::processEvents();
```

The function only takes few seconds.
The box gets displayed but neither the icon nor the text is shown in time before the function finishes. Why does `QApplication::processEvents();` not prevent the program from continuation before the box is completely shown.
Is it possible to achieve the desired behaviour without resorting to threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the processing in a separate thread would be preferable, since that would leave the GUI thread free to do things like handle mouse events, window resizes, etc, while the task is being completed; that way the GUI won't "freeze up" temporarily.

If you don't want to spawn a thread, however, you can call processEvents() periodically from within your analyseFile() function and that will give you roughly the same behavior.  Try to call it at least every 50mS to avoid sluggish GUI response.

A second possibility might be to add a slot somewhere:

```
void MyClass :: ParseFile()
{
   parser.analyseFile(mFileName);
   box->hide();
   box->deleteLater();
}
```

... and then invoke that asynchronously like this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(ParseFile()));
```

... that *might* give the windowing system enough time to finish displaying the QMessageBox before ParseFile() executes, or it might not (in which case you could try to increase the delay argument from 0 to, say, 100 milliseconds instead).  That's a little hacky, but it could work.

Comment: For normal GUIs you are quite right, threads are the way to go. In the present case I don't need any response during the file analysis since it's quite fast. But since I need to analyse several files sometimes I want at least inform the user. Unfortunately even this intormation does not get shown

Comment: Qt can't do its job unless you allow its event loop to run sometimes.

Comment: Sure, but it should do the job BEFORE the function call. Afterwards as well. I don't need anything in between. I just want it to finish it's job before I start the function

Comment: That would be nice, but I think there's enough asynchronicity in Qt's interaction with the OS's windowing system that you can't assume things like that.  Things get done when they're ready to get done, not before.  :^/

Comment: Darn, I sort of feared that. It could have been so simple ...I even tried waiting on QApplication::hasPendingEvents() no luck either. I guess it will be the thread for me ...

Comment: I added a second idea to my answer, see how that works for you.

Comment: As hacky as it is, that did the trick! I'm still wondering which is ugglier. A thread for a simple information box or a timer with 0 timeout ;-)